# How can I change this code in AWS lambda Python to update DynamoDB

Tags: validation, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

How can I change this code in AWS lambda Python to update DynamoDB?

```
    res=table.update_item(
    Key={
        'userid': 'user1'
    },
    UpdateExpression='SET diary[n][6]= :fn',
    ExpressionAttributeValues={":fn" :file_content}

)
return res
```

it causes the following error in [n]:

> An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the UpdateItem operation: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "n", near: "[n]": ClientError

Should I use that variable 'n'?

Comment: What is `diary`? Can you show us how it is being used? And what does `n` represent?

Comment: diary is  dynamoDB's attribute key. it is consist of double list. n is variable index number and i want to update diary double list [n][6] to file_content.   i think its problem of query grammer.  it works well when i put 'SET  diary[1][6]= :fn' .Index of number  works but indnex of  variable doesn't work.

Comment: diary<list<list>>

Comment: Why is the code referring to `n` if it isn't providing a value for `n`? What are your expectations of what it should do? Is `n` being defined in a part of the code you have not included?

Comment: 'n' is index of date of certain diary. diary<date<content>>. it should be used . . .

Comment: how can i amend that code? ㅠㅠ

Comment: Is `n` defined somewhere in your python code? If so, try changing the UpdateExpression to `f'SET diary[{n}][6]= :fn'`